# Expected value of coupled signals is zero

Tags: signal-analysis, noise

Suppose there are two vector signals, $u$ and $v$, which are functions of time. Given, $E[uv^T]=0$, what is the physical significance of this statement. For clarity, assume $u$ and $v$ are noises in a system like in kalman filter, control noise and measurement noise. E is the expected value and assume that the vector dimensions are entirely compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means u and v are orthogonal.

If u or v or both have zero mean then they are also uncorrelated.

If they are uncorrelated and jointly gaussian then they are also independent.